# Ruby: compare two hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two hashes-

```
hash1 = {a: "2", b: "34", c: "53", d: "23", e: "2"}
hash2 = {a: "5", c: "8", d: "3", e: "2", f: "76"}
```

I need compare hashes and get next-

```
hash1_1 = {a: "2", c: "53", d: "23", e: "2"}
hash2_1 = {a: "5", c: "8", d: "3", e: "2"}
```

That is, I need to compare two hash and leave them only those values ​​whose keys are equal and there are both hashes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Denis, thanks for your wit. Just I'm searching best solution for this..

Comment: Sawa, please read my questions again. If you do not see a question mark, it does not mean that question is not present there.

Comment: But anyway you can select both, but check only single with `galka` =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
hash1 = {a: "2", b: "34", c: "53", d: "23", e: "2"}
hash2 = {a: "5", c: "8", d: "3", e: "2", f: "76"}

hash1_1 = hash1.select{|k,_| hash2.has_key? k} 
# => {:a=>"2", :c=>"53", :d=>"23", :e=>"2"}
hash1_2 = hash2.select{|k,_| hash1.has_key? k}
# => {:a=>"5", :c=>"8", :d=>"3", :e=>"2"}
```

Comment: Thanks Arup, this magic solution=)

Answer (score 3):

You can use set intersection, of keys, and `Hash#select`

```
first  = {a: 1, c: 2, e: 3, g: 4}
second = {a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, g: 5}

intersection = first.keys & second.keys # => [:a, :c, :g]

[first, second].map! { |h| h.select { |k, _| intersection.include? k } }

first # => {:a=>1, :c=>2, :e=>3, :g=>4}
second # => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :g=>5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as follows:

```
hash1 = {a: "2", b: "34", c: "53", d: "23", e: "2"}
hash2 = {a: "5", c: "8", d: "3", e: "2", f: "76"}

keys = ( hash1.keys & hash2.keys )
hash1_1 = hash1.select {| k,_ | keys.include? k }
# => {:a=>"2", :c=>"53", :d=>"23", :e=>"2"}
hash2_1 = hash2.select {| k,_ | keys.include? k }
# => {:a=>"5", :c=>"8", :d=>"3", :e=>"2"}
```

Comment: Include the output with your code for verifying... :)

Comment: in which the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach

```
hash1 = {a: "2", b: "34", c: "53", d: "23", e: "2"}
hash2 = {a: "5", c: "8", d: "3", e: "2", f: "76"}

diff1 = (hash1.keys - hash2.keys)
# => [:b]
diff2 = (hash2.keys - hash1.keys)
# => [:f]

hash1_1 = hash1.dup
diff1.each{|k| hash1_1.delete(k)}
hash1_1
# => {:a=>"2", :c=>"53", :d=>"23", :e=>"2"}

hash2_1 = hash2.dup
diff2.each{|k| hash2_1.delete(k)}
hash2_1
# => {:a=>"5", :c=>"8", :d=>"3", :e=>"2"}
```

If you don't need the original hash1 and hash2, you can skip the dup's and delete from hash1 and hash2 directly.