# I have two hash and want to check whether the key in first hash exist in second hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

```
hash1 = simple_hash = {"month" => "January", "number" => "1"}
hash2 = {"number" => "2"}
```

Want to check whether the second hash contains the key in first hash.

I was using this, but not a good approach.

```
simple_hash.each do |k,v|
  hash2.each do |k1,v1|
    if k1==v1
      puts k1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can use `hash.keys` to return an array of the hash keys.

Comment: Refer this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580821/ruby-compare-two-hashes, For this simple case you can use like this hash1 == hash2

Answer (score 4):

To get all common keys:

```
hash1.keys & hash2.keys
# => ["number"]
```

Incase `hash2` always has a single key:

```
hash1.keys.include?(hash2.keys.first)
# => true
```

If you are interested only in:

> Want to check whether the second hash contains the key in first hash.

(irrespective of what key). Then this should be sufficient:

```
!(hash1.keys & hash2.keys).empty?
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `keys` and `include`

like this

```
hash1 = {"month" => "January", "number" => "1"}
hash2 = {"number" => "2"}

hash1.each_key do |k|
  puts k if hash2.keys.include?(k)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash1.keys & hash2.keys
=> ["number"]
```

if

```
hash1 = {"month" => "January"}
hash2 = {"number" => "2"}
hash1.keys & hash2.keys
=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific key you can use:

```
hash1.keys.include?("key_searched")
```

If you want to compare a bunch of keys in hash2 you can use:

```
hash2.keys.each{|k| puts k if hash1.keys.include?(k)}
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `each_key` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/ENV.html#method-c-each_key instead of `keys.each`.